# How to change video source with local file via API "input type='file' " tag...NO Jquery or external libraries

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to change HTML5 video source with a local file via API "input type='file' " tag. This HTML script is meant to run locally only playing videos in my HD but i cant get the "input" tag to select and play video files on my HD.
[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/PixelPimp/q3hhk17e/2/)

HTML

```
<!----------------HOW to cahnge VID source Localy--------------------->
<p>working example</p>
<div id="selectFile">
<p>Change VID:
    <br>

    <button onclick="changeVID()">Change VID</button>

</div>
<div>
<video muted controls  id="videoPlayer" >
        <source id='currentVID' src="http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch9/media/elephants-dream-medium.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    </video>
</div>
<!----------desired result--------------->
<br>
<div id="desired result" style="background-color:grey;">
<p>desired result</p>
<br>

<div id="selectFile">
<p>Change local VID:
    <br>
<input id="newlocalFILE" name="localfile" size="50" maxlength="100000"
    accept="text/*" type="file" onchange="playlocalVID();">

</div>
<div>
<video muted controls  id="videoPlayer" >
        <source id='currentVID' src="c:\LocalVID.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    </video>
</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
/***********working example****************/

function changeVID(){
        var player = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
        var currentVID = document.getElementById('currentVID');
        currentVID.setAttribute('src', "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4");
        player.load();
        player.play();
}


/***********desired result****************/


function CangelocalVID(){
        var player = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
        var currentVID =  document.getElementById('currentVID');
        var selectedLocalVID = document.getElementById('newlocalFILE').value;
        currentVID.setAttribute('src',selectedLocalVID);
        player.load();
        player.play();
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding the file protocol? ```file:///c:/path/to/file``` note the triple slash needs to be present

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Substituted name of video upload handler `playlocalVID` for `CangelocalVID` ; `document.getElementById('newlocalFILE').files[0]` for `document.getElementById('newlocalFILE').value` ; tried with video ["Science Commons"](http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm) from [Creative Commons - Science Commons](http://creativecommons.org/videos/sciencecommons) ; appeared to upload , play video at jsfiddle from local upload

---

Try adjusting `accept` attribute at `input` element to `video/*` , utilizing <strike>`Blob` of</strike> `File` object to create [`objectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) from  `selectedLocalVID.files[0]` to set `src` attribute of `currentVID`

---

```js
function playlocalVID() {
  var player = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
  var currentVID = document.getElementById("currentVID");
  var selectedLocalVID = document.getElementById("newlocalFILE").files[0];
  currentVID.setAttribute("src", URL.createObjectURL(selectedLocalVID));
  player.load();
  player.play();
}
```

```html
<div id="desired result" style="background-color:grey;">
  <p>desired result</p>
  <br>
  <div id="selectFile">
    <p>Change local VID:
      <br>
      <input id="newlocalFILE" name="localfile" size="50" maxlength="100000" accept="video/*" type="file" onchange="playlocalVID();">
  </div>
  <div>
    <video muted controls id="videoPlayer">
      <source id="currentVID" src="http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch9/media/elephants-dream-medium.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q3hhk17e/12/

Comment: i tryied the jsfiddle script  and the script posted above, i also change the onchange event to match the function name both in firefox and chrome... still no luck thanks anyways [guest271314](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2801559/guest271314) for your attempt to solve my problem it gave me some new ideas to work with. i'll keep trying

Comment: THANKs!!! [ guest271314](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2801559/guest271314) I found another [ jsfiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/cCCZ2/presentation/) but it was hard form me to read i was in the process of simplifying and interpreting it to match my script when saw your updated answer witch saves me some trial and error. yours is much more comprehensible...THANKS [ guest271314](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2801559/guest271314)

Comment: you don't need to convert it to a `Blob`, `URL.createObjectURL()` does accept `File` object .

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the most simple solution.** 
Works on Chrome & iOS Safari.
[Try it on Codepen](https://codepen.io/joshstovall/pen/oNgXLEG)

```js
function changeVideo() {
  var chosenFile = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
  document.getElementById("theVideo").setAttribute("src", URL.createObjectURL(chosenFile));
}

document.getElementById("myFile").addEventListener("change", changeVideo);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myFile"><br>
<video controls id="theVideo">
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution, IDK why people aren't seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

final working Answer [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PixelPimp/q3hhk17e/9/)

HTML

```
<p>Change local VID:</p>
    <input id="newlocalFILE" name="localfile" size="50" maxlength="100000"
   accept="video/*" type="file" onchange="playlocalVID()">
<video muted controls  id="videoPlayer" >
         <source id='currentVID' src="http://html5multimedia.com/code/ch9/media/elephants-dream-medium.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function playlocalVID() {


  var currentVID = document.getElementById('currentVID');
  var selectedLocalVID = document.getElementById('newlocalFILE').files[0];
  currentVID.setAttribute('src', URL.createObjectURL(selectedLocalVID));
  player.load();
  player.play();
  var SelectedFileName = document.getElementById('newlocalFILE').value;
}
```

Comment: you don't need to convert it to a `Blob`, `URL.createObjectURL()` does accept `File` object .